# Django: JSONField is stored as CharField instead of ModelField

Tags: django

I have a models in which I'm using the `JSONField` (**django-jsonfield==0.9.13**)

```
from jsonfield import JSONField
user_info = JSONField()
```

`user_info = {"name": "suraj"}`

**In django 1.7.2**
   `user_info` is stored as `dict` only which is the expected behaviour

```
user_info = ModelField(allow_null=True, help_text='engine codes and descriptions', model_field=<jsonfield.fields.JSONField: error_json>, required=False)
```

then from database I can get `user_info` as `{"name": "suraj"}` instance of `dict`.

**In django.1.7.10**

```
error_json = CharField(allow_null=True, help_text='engine codes and descriptions', required=False, style={'type': 'textarea'})
```

Is this `user_info` is stored as string `u'{"name": "suraj"}'` instead of `dict`. Any clue how this can be resolved?

Comment: A workaround would be to use `json.loads(u'{"name": "suraj"}')`. This would give you a `dict`.

Comment: Did you test it using Django 1.7.11?